# Kendo grid paging doesnot work when multiple header rows are present

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[image]I have posted this question on kendo forum too and waiting for response.

I am using kendo grid for my ui and paging/sorting work fine until i add multiple rows (tr:2 and tr:3) in my thead. how can i fix this? is there a way around? I am not doing any grouping just simple rows.

```
 <table>
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="firstname">First Name</th>
                <th data-field="surname">Surname</th>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Current Age</th>
                @foreach (MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
                {

                        <th id=@geMapDetail.MapDetailID>Growth</th>

                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <!--get from mapdetails-->
                @foreach (MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
                {

                    <th id="Year-Sem-Term">@geMapDetail.year</th>
                }
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <!--get from mapdetails-->
                @foreach (MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
                {

                        <th>@geMapDetail.shortDescription</th>

                }
            </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
<table/>
```

**my jquery script**

```
$("#MapDetails").kendoGrid(
   {

       sortable: true,
       dataSource: {
           pageSize: 5
       },
       pageable:true,
       resizable: true,
       columns: [{
           field: "firstname",
           width: 150,
           locked: false
           }
       ]
   }


   );
```

Comment: which version of kendo UI you are using? and can you recreate this in jsbin or other web tool. if you can do that, just give the example link. that would be great for the person who would want to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i have done is i have merged all 3/4 rows in one row and spaced them with a "br" tag.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails">

<thead>
    <tr class="">
        <th data-field="firstname">First Name</th>
        <th data-field="surname">Surname</th>
        <th data-field="class">Class</th>
        <th data-field="age">Current Age</th>
      @{

            foreach (MapDetail geMapDetailHead in Model.mapDetails)
            {
              string firstText, secText, thirdText, fourthText;
                //...set all 4 header row values in the above variables
              <th id=@geMapDetailHead.MapDetailID>@firstText<br /><b>@secText</b><br />@thirdText<br /><font size="1">@fourthText</font></th>

            }
       }
```

Served the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the Grid support multiple header rows (except the so-called [multi-column headers](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders)), especially when it is created from an existing table. As far as I can see, a JavaScript error occurs in such cases.

What I can suggest is injecting the additional table rows in the header after Grid initialization. Alternatively, you can try the multi-column headers and have only one child column per parent column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="example">
      <table id="grid">
        <colgroup>
          <col />
          <col />
          <col style="width:110px" />
          <col style="width:120px" />
          <col style="width:130px" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="make">Car Make</th>
            <th data-field="model">Car Model</th>
            <th data-field="year">Year</th>
            <th data-field="category">Category</th>
            <th data-field="airconditioner">Air Conditioner</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Volvo</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>2002</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BMW</td>
            <td>535d</td>
            <td>2006</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BMW</td>
            <td>320d</td>
            <td>2006</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>No</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>VW</td>
            <td>Passat</td>
            <td>2007</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>No</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>VW</td>
            <td>Passat</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peugeot</td>
            <td>407</td>
            <td>2006</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Honda</td>
            <td>Accord</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>No</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfa Romeo</td>
            <td>159</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>No</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nissan</td>
            <td>Almera</td>
            <td>2001</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mitsubishi</td>
            <td>Lancer</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Opel</td>
            <td>Vectra</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Toyota</td>
            <td>Avensis</td>
            <td>2006</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>No</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Toyota</td>
            <td>Avensis</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Toyota</td>
            <td>Avensis</td>
            <td>2008</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>Q7</td>
            <td>2007</td>
            <td>SUV</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hyundai</td>
            <td>Santa Fe</td>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>SUV</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hyundai</td>
            <td>Santa Fe</td>
            <td>2013</td>
            <td>SUV</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nissan</td>
            <td>Qashqai</td>
            <td>2007</td>
            <td>SUV</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mercedez</td>
            <td>B Class</td>
            <td>2007</td>
            <td>Hatchback</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lancia</td>
            <td>Ypsilon</td>
            <td>2006</td>
            <td>Hatchback</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            dataSource: {
              pageSize: 5
            }
          });
          
          $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").thead.append('<tr><th class="k-header">Row 2</th><th class="k-header">Row 2</th><th class="k-header">Row 2</th><th class="k-header">Row 2</th><th class="k-header">Row 2</th></tr>');
        });
      </script>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```